# is it possible to use both the new and old input systems in different Unity scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine

currently making a Unity project and have switched from using the old input system to the new one, but in changed input system older parts of the program have broken. Is it possible it can retain the old input system for old scenes and start using the new system for newer scenes, maybe theres a script that can change them in the Unity engine?

Answer (score 1):

I have honestly not attempted this myself, so this may not work as expected. But if you go to Project Settings -> Player -> Other Settings, there is a dropdown named Active Input Handling, which controls which system you use for input. There is an option for Both.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the same process of switching from "Input Manager"(old) to "Input System"(new). I can confirm, as Grailas mentioned, that to use both systems at the same time, you have to select the option "Both" under: Project Settings -> Player -> Other Settings - Configuration - Active Input Handling.

You can use your old code for the "Input Manager" and add new code for the new "Input System" at the same time without any issue.

Comment: alternatively, you can use the [Conditional Compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) "ENABLE_INPUT_SYSTEM" and "ENABLE_LEGACY_INPUT_MANAGER" to track which system you are using